# How to load related entities, that can be null in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

A quick question (simplified scenario):

There are 3 simple tables (connected 1:many):

**Car** <-- **Model** <-- **Make**

1. `Car`, w/ columns: `CarId`, `ModelId`
2. `Model`, w/ columns: `ModelId`, `MakeId`
3. `Make`, w/ columns: `MakeId`

Using eager loading, I'm doing:

```
var car = fni.Cars.AsNoTracking()
          .Include(c => c.Model.Make)
          .Where(c => c.CarId == carId);
```

The problem I have is that Make can be NULL. Simply, there can be a car with a coresponsing Model, but w/o Make! For such a car my function returns "null" and then the car is null. But it's not! I'm looking for something like:

```
var car = fni.Cars.AsNoTracking()
          .Include(c => (c.Model.Make == null) ? c.Model : c.Model.Make)
          .Where(c => c.CarId == carId);
```

But that doesn't work..

**EDIT:**

Three strange things:

**First strage thing**, when I do:

```
var car = fni.Cars.AsNoTracking()
          .Include(c => c.Model)
          .Where(c => c.CarId == carId);
```

If the car has a `Make` it is included!

If the car has not a `Make` it is null obvously.

**Second strange thing.** That doesn't work!:

```
var car = fni.Cars.AsNoTracking()
  .Include(c => c.Model)
  .Where(c => c.CarId == carId)
  .Select(c => new CarDto(){
    ...
    MakeName = (c.Model != null && c.Model.Make != null) ? c.Model.Make.Name : "",
    ...
  })
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Third, the strangest thing!** That condition `(c.Model != null && c.Model.MakeId < 0)` works. It returns "1" for not null make and "2" for a null make:

```
var car = fni.Cars.AsNoTracking()
  .Include(c => c.Model)
  .Where(c => c.CarId == carId)
  .Select(c => new CarDto(){
    ...
    MakeName = (c.Model != null && c.Model.MakeId < 0) ? "1" : "2",
    ...
  })
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

but.. I If do **THIS**, for a Car w/o Make it doesn't return "2" anymore. The whole car is null!

```
var car = fni.Cars.AsNoTracking()
  .Include(c => c.Model)
  .Where(c => c.CarId == carId)
  .Select(c => new CarDto(){
    ...
    MakeName = (c.Model != null && c.Model.MakeId < 0) ? c.Model.Make : "2",
    ...
  })
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Basically, whenever I touch "Make" when it's null - it returns NULL for the `car`.

EDIT2: The problem and solution:

The problem:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<FniContext>(null);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Make>().HasMany(i => i.Models).WithRequired(i => i.Make).HasForeignKey(s => s.MakeId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().HasMany(i => i.Cars).WithRequired(i => i.Model).HasForeignKey(s => s.ModelId);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The solution:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Make>().HasMany(i => i.Models).WithOptional(i => i.Make).HasForeignKey(s => s.MakeId)
```

Comment: at the beginning I thought that there was a 1-n relation between Model and Make. But this does seem to be the case. Do you have an actual error with .Include(c => c.Model.Make) ? For me, it's working. EF should generate a LEFT join in this case.  Is Model.MakeId correctly marked as nullable ?

Comment: @Pac0 something really strange is happening.. can you look at my EDIT? I posted 3 strange things that happens :/ really weird BTW. `MakeId` is nullable

Comment: @Marshall We need to see your entity model and configuration, not "strange things". As Pac0 pointed out, most likely you have incorrect configuration so EF thinks the `MakeId` is required. Also you'd better check the generated SQL - if it contains `INNER JOIN`s instead of  `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.

Comment: @IvanStoev sure, one sec

Comment: Two things in addition of Ivan Stoev's comment : First, ''That doesn't work!:' is quite unclear (for second case). Second : don't forget that all this Linq queries are performed on DB side . So we may need to know which DB you are using. For the Select, maybe you can **First** get your car object with the first simple method that works, and **then** create your CarDTO from that (since you are just taking one car object, you don't need to create the object in a Linq query, and even if you have a lot of them you can use Linq on the result list that should solve anything" caused by DB EF driver

Comment: @Pac0 Guys.. sorry! I found the problem it was about the entity configuration. As I was writing an edit I spotted this: `modelBuilder.Entity<Make>().HasMany(i => i.Models).WithRequired(i => i.Make).HasForeignKey(s => s.MakeId);` 

The id was null able, but it configuration has overridden it. Thanks for help!

Comment: @IvanStoev I solved it. It was a stupid mistake. Look at my EDIT2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what I had in mind :) Happy coding.